# Would a SO variant for graphic designers go down well?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

Would a SO variant for graphic designers go down well?

There are literally millions of tutorials on blogs the internet that cater for learning new graphic design techniques/discussions.

A SO variant could act as a central repository for people to post their free tutorials, as well as to ask for opinions on designs, font usage etc etc.

As a side, it would also give those web-developers on SO a place to go looking for graphic designers who do freelance work etc (further expanding the jobs board)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

This site now exists as [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). It’s even graduated, with its own shiny new graphic-designy theme.

Answer (score 1):

They would definitely need to implement image-uploading for that project. I would love to see one for designing though: everything from Photoshop to Maya.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.StackExchange.com

We can't expect Atwood to create a new one for all of our dreams, afterall.

Comment: While I agree with that, it would pretty much complete the quadrilogy of stackoverflow sites. What programmer doesn't need a graphic designer from time to time for UI Designs, icons etc.

..Or what web-developer doesn't dabble in photo shop himself attempting to create designs too, but needs some feedback?

Comment: Maybe it would be a useful 4th site (even though Meta is that 3rd/4th already), but you could go one step further and then think of what would be the most fitting 5th, 6th, 7th, etc. Eventually these types of requests need to just go and die somewhere. If there is enough interest in it, I am sure someone will use the StackExchange engine to build it. And the likelihood would increase even more if the rumored potential open-source version comes to fruition.

Comment: You know what would complete the quintilogy of SO sites?  A site about cars, because what programmer doesn't ride in one from time to time?

Comment: The septilogy would be completed with a SO variant based solely on posting pictures and descriptions of ideal work spaces including chair models, monitor sizes, and keyboard layouts.

Comment: @TheTXI: Including photos of people's overflowing stacks of paper, thus making the circle complete!

Comment: Programmers all use chairs. We need a chair sitting Q&A site.

Comment: "How to sit in chair for long time"

Comment: @RichB: And a meta site for it.  "What's the best way to refer to your ass when discussing sitting?"  "Retag Request: wheels => casters"  "Why does someone keep making edits to my question titles?"

Comment: "Feature Request: Fix wheel on right side of chair"

Comment: "As a person who sits in a chair, what is your favorite pony?"

Comment: "How do I program while standing up?  [closed: not sitting related]"

Comment: "What's your favorite chair to sit in on a boat?"

Comment: "As person who sits on chair - who is your favorite band?"

Comment: I am declaring Pesto the official winner of this comment thread.

Comment: "What do I need to know about chair sitting on a boat?"

Comment: Can we make this site happen now?  It could be called ChairOverflow, and the logo would be an ass spilling over the sides of a seat.

Comment: @Pesto: I nominate a pic of thetxi.

Comment: @JonB, shouldn't there be 6 sites in the stackoverflow series. I can see why a designer one would make sense considering the amount of web questions (HTML) on stackoverflow

Comment: plz to clz chris' comment. It is not chair-related.

Comment: @chris, probably. With design.stackoverflow & chair.stackoverflow we'd be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the SO model is right for tutorials.  It doesn't really fit into the Q&A structure, and the sort of long-form, lots-of-images answers necessary for such a site don't really work especially well with SO.  Aren't there already repositories out there for tutorials?

Comment: Sure, there are. But there is no great way to search, reasonably reliably, for good ones or recommended ones.

Comment: I agree that having a measure of reliability would improve them, but that doesn't make it a candidate for SO replacement.  For one, SO is terrible for searching, too.  I think something akin to the GameFAQs model might be better.

Comment: SO is to life what jQuery is to SO and what Greasemonkey is to MetaSO