# What are these mysterious empty tags in the revision history?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, meta, revisions-list

While glancing at the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5243/revisions) of [Would a SO variant for graphic designers go down well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243/223030), I noticed that both of the tag edits (revisions 3 and 6) contain mysterious empty tags:

> [image: 6: -[stackoverflow-expansion] [] [discussion] +[site-proposal]]
>   [image: 3: [stackoverflow-expansion] [] +[discussion]]

What are these mysterious empty tags (linking to `/questions/tagged/`)? Why are they there?

Comment: MSO-MSE split artefacts?

Comment: Most likely [that was me](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html); looking...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are legacies of a [long history](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html) of  how we store tag data. Yesterday I completed our migration, but the migrate script did not quite allow for some broken-but-just-about-working data. In this case (you'll need to read the blog for this to make sense) the old data was:

```
éfooà  ébarà
```

Note the two spaces. Unfortunately, this got migrated to

```
|foo| |bar|
```

which is clearly wrong. Fixes en-route. Thanks for noticing my failure :(

Edit; looks fine to me... you were clearly hallucinating:

[image]

Depending on what that tablet is, either take less of them or take more of them.

<sub>(Stack Exchange does not offer medical or psychological advice; please consult a relevant professional before adjusting your medication)</sub>